# Can a website store the facebook user id locally?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, web

I want to keep the user id of the Facebook user in my website and use it instead of the user authenticating it every time.

Is it possible or are there any copyright issue for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should do it if you don't want your users to remember yet another userid and password.

There is not copyright issue in doing so.